# trying to make an average calculator using count

Tags: python, average, calculator

this is what I have so far

```py
how_many = int(input("How many numbers do you want to average? "))
for counter in range(1,(how_many+1)):
    numbers=int(input("Enter a number to be averaged "))
    print(numbers/how_many)
```

any ideas?

Comment: You should add the new int inside the loop, and only when the loop is finished divide by the amount

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like the following:

```
how_many = int(input("How many numbers do you want to average? "))
numbers=0
for counter in range(1,(how_many+1)):
    numbers+=int(input("Enter a number to be averaged "))
print(numbers/how_many)
```

You should always add checks that the input is the one that you expect, for instance if the input will be a string the program will break. Refer to the following for example https://pynative.com/python-check-user-input-is-number-or-string/

Answer (score 0):

You have to first add them in a list:
So the code will be:

```
how_many = int(input("How many numbers do you want to average? "))
numb = []
for counter in range(1,(how_many+1)):
    numbers=int(input("Enter a number to be averaged "))
    numb.append(numbers)

print(sum(numb)/how_many)
```